# Powershell dates to Sharepoint Dates

Tags: sharepoint, date, powershell

I have an old site that I am trying to convert to sharepoint.  I have a database that stores the original upload date of the document.  I need to get that date into a sharepoint column called "Original Upload".  The "Original Upload" column is in a date/time format and only displays the date like "10/5/2009".  I created a Powershell script to grab the date from the database and use it to change the "Original Upload" date in sharepoint.  The problem is I keep getting a powershell error of "invalid date/time".

Powershell formats the date from the database as "Friday, May 06, 2011 7:52:12 AM".  Sharepoint does not accept this date format.  Sharepoint also does not accept strings.  I was able to change the format of the powershell date to "5/6/2011" (the format on the sharepoint site), but it is converted from an object to a string, which doesn't work.

How do I convert a powershell date to "5/6/2011" and keep it as an object so Sharepoint will accept it?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sharepoint accepts iso date format which have format:

```
yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ssZ
```

in your example:

```
2011-05-06T07:52:12Z
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  I have been trying to figure this out for the past 2 days.  That worked perfectly.

Comment: Note the first 'mm' for month had to be uppercase to work for me:          $updatedMembershipDate = (Get-Date $member["membershipdate"]).AddDays(1).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ssZ");

Comment: @aalesund you are correct, fixed, thanks!